# Logstash filter to identify address matches

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash-configuration

I have a CSV file with customer addresses. I have also an Elasticsearch index with my own addresses. I use Logstash as tool to import the CSV file. I'd like to use a logstash filter to check in my index if the customer address already exists. All I found is the default elasticsearch filter ("Copies fields from previous log events in Elasticsearch to current events") which doesn't look the correct one to solve my problem. Does another filter exist for my problem?

Here my configuration file so far:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/import/Logstash/customer.CSV"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
    columns => [
      "Customer",
      "City",
      "Address",
      "State",
      "Postal Code"
      ]
      separator => ";"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
      index => "customer-unmatched"
    }
    stdout{}
}
```

Comment: How do you define "the customer address already exists"? Does it have an unique ID? Or is it based on an exact match of all the values "city", "address", "state", "postal code"?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: My ES index is based on company adresses we collected and now I'd like to check if the imported addresses from my customer already exist in my index, like a fuzzy matching, Our Index has an ID, yes but not the addresses from my customer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally have access to the data in Elasticsearch while processing your Logstash event. Consider using a [pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-pipeline) on an [Ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html)